# Shell - Print values in a comma separated string

Tags: linux, shell, printing, echo, readline

I have a txt file with some comma separated values.

```
cat file.txt

abc,def,ghi
abc,ghi
def,abc,ghi
def,abc
abc,def
abc,def,ghi
```

I want to print these values with `while do read line from file` separated by comma.

### Eg:

```
expecting output for Line no 1:
first col=abc
second col=def
third col=ghi
expecting output for Line no 2:
first col=abc
second col=ghi
```

If the line has three values then the read line should print

```
first col=value
second col=value
third col=value
```

else

```
first col=value
second col=value
```

How can I create this shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, '{ print "line " NR; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { print "Col " i "="$i } }' input
line 1
Col 1=abc
Col 2=def
Col 3=ghi
line 2
Col 1=abc
Col 2=ghi
line 3
Col 1=def
Col 2=abc
Col 3=ghi
line 4
Col 1=def
Col 2=abc
line 5
Col 1=abc
Col 2=def
line 6
Col 1=abc
Col 2=def
Col 3=ghi
```

If you really want to transliterate from numerical columns to "first", "second", et cetera, you can define an array and use `i` as the index to look up the word that matches the number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its awesome, If I want to use the same case instead of a file, I want to do inline, like `  awk -F, '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { print "Col " i "="$i } }' "abc,def,ghi" ` How can I use the same command for this?

Comment: `echo "abc,def,ghi" | awk [...]`

Answer (score 1):

With bash you could do

```
ordinals=( first second third fourth fifth sixth )
n=0
while IFS=, read -ra cols; do
    echo "line $((++n))"
    for i in "${!cols[@]}"; do
        echo "${ordinals[i]} col=${cols[i]}"
    done
done < file
```

That reads the words in each line into an array named `cols`, then we interate over the *indices* of that array so we can correlate the value to the ordinal.

For the first 3 lines, we get

```
line 1
first col=abc
second col=def
third col=ghi
line 2
first col=abc
second col=ghi
line 3
first col=def
second col=abc
third col=ghi
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input file only has at most three columns, the following uses a `while`-`read` loop to read the comma-separated values from standard input and outputs them in a format similar to what you showed:

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS=, read -r first second third
do
    printf 'Line %d:\n' "$(( ++n ))"
    ${first:+printf 'First:\t%s\n' "$first"}
    ${second:+printf 'Second:\t%s\n' "$second"}
    ${third:+printf 'Third:\t%s\n' "$third"}
done
```

The parameter expansion `${variable:+word}` expands to `word` if `variable` is set and non-empty.  The code uses this to execute `printf` for output if the corresponding variable contains data to be printed.

Testing on the provided data:

```
$ ./script.sh <file
Line 1:
First:  abc
Second: def
Third:  ghi
Line 2:
First:  abc
Second: ghi
Line 3:
First:  def
Second: abc
Third:  ghi
Line 4:
First:  def
Second: abc
Line 5:
First:  abc
Second: def
Line 6:
First:  abc
Second: def
Third:  ghi
```